# Debugging in Eclipse - How to check when a value of a String becomes null instead of printing everywhere

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

Does anybody know how to use Eclipse to see to what point a string value becomes null for debugging purpose, instead of printing?

Comment: Please elaborate...are you seeing a string become null and you want to find out where?

Comment: are you getting a NullPointerException ?

Comment: Look at the Answer in the linked Question that describes "watch points".

Answer (score 0):

You have a view in debug mode of eclipse "variables", you can give the name of the variable there and you can monitor the value of it when running through your code.